# Powershell improved performance and coding efficiency scraping text and outputting to file

Tags: powershell, validation, parsing

First time writing a PS script. The source is supposed to be pipe-delimited data which conforms to some constraints. This script is to identify records in the source which violate some of the rules. I've mainly used the Microsoft documentation to learn enough to get me to this point.

Questions:

1. Are there alternatives to ReadLines, out-file, or the way I've structured the foreach loop which would perform better on very large files (~tens of GB)?
2. Is it possible to store code  in an array/function/? in order to access it later and execute it with an argument. E.g., instead of writing the logic for regex or string length comparison per line, perhaps a function for string length which accepts a string and a lenght, does the evaluation and passes or fails?
3. How do I determine the minimum version for the various cmdlets I'm using?
4. Are there existing cmdlets which handle the type of validation I'm trying to do natively?

Thank you

```
$record=''
$ary=''
$Nrecord=0
foreach ($record in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines("..."))
{
$results=''
$Nrecord++
$ary=$record.split('|')
if(($ary[0])    -and ($ary[0].length -gt 50))       {$results=$results + "$Nrecord|1|A|String length`r"} 
if(($ary[1])    -and ($ary[1].length -gt 50))       {$results=$results + "$Nrecord|2|A|String length`r"}
if(($ary[2])    -and ($ary[2] -notmatch "^[012]{1}$"))  {$results=$results + "$Nrecord|3|B|Category`r"}
if(($ary[4])    -and ($ary[4] -notmatch "^[0-9]{2}$"))  {$results=$results + "$Nrecord|5|B|Category`r"}
if(($ary[5])    -and ($ary[5] -notmatch "^[123]{1}$"))  {$results=$results + "$Nrecord|6|B|Category`r"}
if(($ary[6])    -and ($ary[6].length -gt 10))       {$results=$results + "$Nrecord|7|A|String length`r"}
if(($ary[7])    -and ($ary[7] -notmatch "^[0-9]{8}$"))  {$results=$results + "$Nrecord|8|C|Date`r"}
if(($ary[8])    -and ($ary[8] -notmatch "^[0-9]{8}$"))  {$results=$results + "$Nrecord|9|C|Date`r"}
if(($ary[9])    -and ($ary[9] -notmatch "^.{2}$"))  {$results=$results + "$Nrecord|10|B|Category`r"}
if(($ary[10])   -and ($ary[10] -notmatch "^.{2}$"))     {$results=$results + "$Nrecord|11|B|Category`r"}
if(($ary[11])   -and ($ary[11] -notmatch "^.{2}$"))     {$results=$results + "$Nrecord|12|B|Category`r"}
if(($ary[12])   -and ($ary[12] -notmatch "^.{2}$"))     {$results=$results + "$Nrecord|13|A|Category`r"}
if(($ary[13])   -and ($ary[13].length -gt 10))      {$results=$results + "$Nrecord|14|A|String length`r"}
if(($ary[14])   -and ($ary[14].length -gt 10))      {$results=$results + "$Nrecord|15|A|String length`r"}
if(($ary[16])   -and ($ary[16].length -gt 10))      {$results=$results + "$Nrecord|17|A|String length`r"}
if(($ary[18])   -and ($ary[17].length -gt 4))       {$results=$results + "$Nrecord|19|A|String length`r"}
if(($ary[26])   -and ($ary[26].length -gt 10))      {$results=$results + "$Nrecord|27|A|String length`r"}
if(($ary[27])   -and ($ary[27].length -gt 10))      {$results=$results + "$Nrecord|28|A|String length`r"}
if(($ary[29])   -and ($ary[29].length -gt 10))      {$results=$results + "$Nrecord|30|A|String length`r"}
if(($ary[30])   -and ($ary[30] -notmatch "^[01]{1}$"))  {$results=$results + "$Nrecord|31|B|Category`r"}
$results.TrimEnd("`r") | out-file -filepath "..." -append
}
```

Comment: You might do a step back and take a little time to learn the basics of Powershell from scratch. I think it's beyond the scope of SO to teach you step by step how to write scripts.

Comment: Agree with Olaf on this one and vote to close to put on hold as to broad. However, user5489286, use this discussion(s) to ramp up on what you need to know and how to attack it one step at a time. https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/afqmmw/i_want_to_help_my_husband_advance_his_powershell/ee3k6p6/?context=3

Comment: Welcome to Powershell. I love that you're asking for feedback. Leveraging feedback from folks that have written more Posh is a pro move. You'll get less static posting this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/; telling you for reference.

Comment: I think there is a typo on `$ary[12]`. Shouldn't the result be `"$Nrecord|13|B|Category"` (`B` instead of `A`)?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a CSV file named `sample.csv` that looks like the following:

```
1,lori renier,shark
2,marc cuban,shark
3,adam,tuna
4,Olaf,Chubb
```

I'd load the data with something like...

```
$contents = Import-CSV -Path .\sample.csv -Delimiter ',' -Header @('id','name','type')
```

Then I'd loop through the contents doing whatever clean I needed to do...

```
foreach ($record in $contents) {
    if ($record.id.length -eq '') { $record.id = ... }
    if ($record.name -eq '') { $record.name = ... }
    if ($record.type -eq '') { $record.type = ... }
}
```

Then I'd export out the clean results...

```
Export-CSV -Path .\clean.csv -Delimiter ',' -Encoding 'ASCII' -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

The .NET methods/objects are usually faster. So, using `[System.IO.File]::ReadLines("...")` will probably perform a bit better, but Powershell folks generally bias available commandlets first before falling back to .NET code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would help you much, but you could create two small testing functions to simplify the code somewhat. Also, instead of doing so many string concatenations (`$results=$results + ...`) I think using a Stringbuilder object would perform a lot better.

```
function Test-Length ([string]$value,[int]$size) {
    return (!([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($value)) -and $value.Length -gt $size) 
}

function Test-NotMatch([string]$value,[string]$regex) {
    return (!([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($value)) -and $value -notmatch $regex)
}

$Nrecord = 0
# use a StringBuilder object for better performance
$results = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Text.StringBuilder'
foreach ($record in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines("...")) {
    $ary=$record.split('|')
    $Nrecord++
    # $i is the array index counter that makes it easier to write the result
    $i = 0

    if (Test-Length $ary[$i++] 50)             {[void]$results.AppendLine("$Nrecord|$i|A|String length")}
    if (Test-Length $ary[$i++] 50)             {[void]$results.AppendLine("$Nrecord|$i|A|String length")}
    if (Test-NotMatch $ary[$i++] "^[012]{1}$") {[void]$results.AppendLine("$Nrecord|$i|B|Category")}
    $i++     # skipping element 3. Not important?
    if (Test-NotMatch $ary[$i++] "^[0-9]{2}$") {[void]$results.AppendLine("$Nrecord|$i|B|Category")}
    if (Test-NotMatch $ary[$i++] "^[123]{1}$") {[void]$results.AppendLine("$Nrecord|$i|B|Category")}
    if (Test-Length $ary[$i++] 10)             {[void]$results.AppendLine("$Nrecord|$i|A|String length")}
    if (Test-NotMatch $ary[$i++] "^[0-9]{8}$") {[void]$results.AppendLine("$Nrecord|$i|C|Date")}
    if (Test-NotMatch $ary[$i++] "^[0-9]{8}$") {[void]$results.AppendLine("$Nrecord|$i|C|Date")}
    if (Test-NotMatch $ary[$i++] "^.{2}$")     {[void]$results.AppendLine("$Nrecord|$i|B|Category")}
    if (Test-NotMatch $ary[$i++] "^.{2}$")     {[void]$results.AppendLine("$Nrecord|$i|B|Category")}
    if (Test-NotMatch $ary[$i++] "^.{2}$")     {[void]$results.AppendLine("$Nrecord|$i|B|Category")}
    if (Test-NotMatch $ary[$i++] "^.{2}$")     {[void]$results.AppendLine("$Nrecord|$i|B|Category")}
    if (Test-Length $ary[$i++] 10)             {[void]$results.AppendLine("$Nrecord|$i|A|String length")}
    if (Test-Length $ary[$i++] 10)             {[void]$results.AppendLine("$Nrecord|$i|A|String length")}
    $i++    # skipping element 15. Not important?
    if (Test-Length $ary[$i++] 10)             {[void]$results.AppendLine("$Nrecord|$i|A|String length")}
    $i++    # skipping element 17. Not important?
    if (Test-Length $ary[$i++] 4)              {[void]$results.AppendLine("$Nrecord|$i|A|String length")}
    $i = 26 # skipping elements 19 to 25. Not important?
    if (Test-Length $ary[$i++] 10)             {[void]$results.AppendLine("$Nrecord|$i|A|String length")}
    if (Test-Length $ary[$i++] 10)             {[void]$results.AppendLine("$Nrecord|$i|A|String length")}
    $i++    # skipping element 28. Not important?
    if (Test-Length $ary[$i++] 10)             {[void]$results.AppendLine("$Nrecord|$i|A|String length")}
    if (Test-NotMatch $ary[$i++] "^[01]{1}$")  {[void]$results.AppendLine("$Nrecord|$i|B|Category")}

    Add-Content -Path "..." -Value $results.ToString()
    # we're reusing the stringbuilder for the next iteration
    [void]$results.Clear()
}
```

Comment: For this solution, I expected that $i would increment each time it was used as an index value ($ary[$i++]), but it doesn't. Is that behavior something that needs to be enabled in my instance?

Comment: @DAWG Huh? I cannot reproduce that. The index variable `$i` gets increased like expected in all my test cases. You can test this by writing a lot of `Write-Host "Index now: $i"` before each `if(...)` or by temporarily have the functions always return `$true` and then look at the second column in the output of `$results.ToString()`

Comment: @DAWG Also, in your example code, you are skipping array elements 17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25 and 28. Is that done with a reason, or just an oversight?